# Error upgrading "Subscriptions" from 1.6 to 4.0.1

Tags: upgrade, subscriptions

I've just upgraded from EE2 to EE5, everything's working great however when I try to upgrade the eeHarbour module "Subscriptions" from 1.6 to 4.0.1 I get the following error:

```
Warning
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Addons\Addons' does not have a method 'select'
ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Legacy/Facade.php, line 78

Severity: E_WARNING

Fatal error: Call to a member function from() on null in /chroot/home/html/site/system/user/addons/subs/Updates/1_07_00.php on line 22
```

Any ideas? I've checked to make sure the select fieldtype is in `system/ee/EllisLab/Addons/select` and all seems to be fine there.

Comment: worth noting i'm running php 5.6.40 and EE 5.3.0

Comment: It's worth testing on PHP7